# 10.4 IDE Cuts Off Component Toolbar

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I downloaded latest Delphi IDE (10.4) and installed it. I turned off the embedded designer and set the layout to Classic Undocked.

Now the toolbar, in fact everything in the top form, is cut off. Can't see the save icons, run button or anything else. Also can't expand the form to make it taller.

[image]

If I change to startup layout it will let me expand the form, but I prefer Classic Undocked. Has anyone else had this yet and, more importantly, does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Probably best to wait for a patch or 10.4.1 and meanwhile stay with docked layout .

Comment: And in the meantime, be sure to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: [RSP-29118: Component Palette only partial visible](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-29118): "*Workaround: Place an unused section below the component palette, then it is at least partly visible*"

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on a workaround for this problem.  Here are the steps that makes the entire tool panel visible for me in Classic Undocked mode for Delphi 10.4 Sydney (on Win 7):

*Grab the right edge of the top form (Classic Toolbar) and resize it slightly (make sure it is in Resizeable mode, not Full Screen).  Zap! now everything works.  Not only that, it appears to remember the "lesson" permanently once this has been done once - it is a complete and permanent fix.*

This bug should be trivial for Embarcadero to fix.